# One computer's download speeds are slow, but speedtest remains fast. The other computer, on the other hand, is always fast

Tags: networking, internet-speed

One of my older computers has been suffering from a weird problem where when I download something, regardless of where I download from, speeds are really slow.

I have a 1000 Mb fiber line and one computer can consistently go over 90MB/s when trying to download Genshin Impact (their servers are amazingly fast), but the other one can't go past 4MB/s. 8 minutes vs 3 hours to download the whole thing.

Other examples are downloading a YouTube video or an update from a program.
Speeds are consistently slower on the slow computer.

All these actions took seconds on my computer, but took minutes to hours on the other computer, yet Ookla's speedtest returns comparable results with a margin of error on both computers.

Both computers are running Windows 10 and both have a Gigabit NIC. Drivers are up to date.

Things I did:

- Checked that the cable is good (i used 3 different cables).
- Checked that there are no QoS setting enabled in the router. (Inteno DG200 provided by my ISP (Adamo))
- Resetted and upgraded the firmware of the Netgear Switch between the router and the affected computer. There is no QoS enabled either. (GS108Ev3 V2.06.17EN)
- Verified that the network card in the affected computer is working at Gigabit full duplex speeds.
- Booted up Linux Mint and tried downloading stuff, which downloaded much faster than in Windows.

At this point I've run out of ideas. What could be making download speeds so slow? Please don't tell me that it's because the server is slow. I know that. That's why I'm testing with several sources. ;P

---

To answer to the comments:

- `Is the Ethernet card set to "auto negotiation" or was it forced to Gigabit speed?`

  - It's auto negotiated.
- `Have you tried iperf3 between computers within your LAN (bypassing the Internet connection and the storage), both over IPv4 and IPv6?`

  - I just tried iperf3 and results were good, ~90 Mbytes per seconds both ways.

````
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   881 MBytes  88.1 MBytes/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec   881 MBytes  88.1 MBytes/sec                  receiver```

- `Check to see if the MTU is set the same on the network interfaces of both systems.`
    - MTU is set to 1500 in both computers. Even enabling Jumbo package to 9000 didn't made a difference.

The only thing I have to still check is netstat or tracert.
````

Comment: I forgot to add that we are using SSDs so that should not be the issue.

Comment: Can you check whether both computers are downloading the game from the _same_ CDN servers? (netstat or similar tools would be enough here.) Is the Ethernet card set to "auto negotiation" or was it forced to Gigabit speed? Have you tried iperf3 between computers within your LAN (bypassing the Internet connection _and_ the storage), both over IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: Check to see if the MTU is set the same on the network interfaces of both systems.

Comment: TCP parameters? A very thorough AV? Network route?

Comment: Thank you for the comments. I've already tested some of your suggestions and I'm about to try checking the route and netstat